# "Input string was not in a correct format" error in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

First I should mention that I know there are several questions similar to mine, but none of them could help me.

I want to compare two dates which are in two different SQL table and I'm using Lambda Expression.

My code:

```
var itemStartDate = new ItemsBusiness().GetList<Item>(i => Convert.ToInt64(i.StartDate.Replace("/", "")) < Convert.ToInt64(tdpStartDate.Text.Replace("/", "")));
```

However when I run the program, this exception shows up:

> Input string was not in a correct format. When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

The line which catches the exception is in another form:

```
try
{
    int inputVal = Convert.ToInt32(value.Trim().Replace("px", ""));
    myLabelWidth = inputVal.ToString();
}
```

p.s: My dates format is like this: "2010/06/20"

Comment: Can't you try to parse as date instead of this method?

Comment: Are you sure its in this line you get the error? It seems more likely that its within the object Item that you get this error

Comment: @helgeheldre No, it's in another line; however this line causes it.

Comment: @iminiki - Please show what is the data within `i.StartDate` and `tdpStartDate.Date` and also how the data was put into the variables

Comment: If you provide that line of code too it will be even easier for people to help you out

Comment: I think we will also need the code for your `Item` class and `GetList<T>` method

Comment: @shree.pat18 I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I think is happening. I assume that you turn your `date` into a `string` like this:

```
var StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
var tdpStartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
var result = Convert.ToInt64(StartDate.Replace("/", "")) < Convert.ToInt64(tdpStartDate.Replace("/", ""));
```

This will fail with the error you got because the `Date` is in a format with letters when representing the month.

What you can do is simply to format the `Date` to include nothing but digits:

```
var StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
var tdpStartDate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
var result = Convert.ToInt64(StartDate) < Convert.ToInt64(tdpStartDate);
```

This does not throw the exception like before

Comment: I'm not using the current date, it's two different dates in two different tables.